# This with Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I've made a component with a simle service.
I want to achieve the following behavior - When my service's http.get request is completed - use the received parameters for another get request.

However, the `this.sections[0].Id` parameter of the Groupservice request is undefined, and the current this does not have a section parameter.  though the data received from data.json is correct.

The code is (imports appended)

```
@Component({
    template: require('./content.component.html'),
    styles: [require('./content.component.css')],
    providers: [SectionService, GroupService]
})
export class ContentComponent {
    id: string;
    sections: Array<Section>;
    groups: Array<Group>
    selectedSectionTitle: "";
    constructor(private router: Router, private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute, private sectionService: SectionService, private groupService: GroupService) {
        this.router.events.subscribe(path => {
            this.id = activateRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
        });
        this.id = activateRoute.snapshot.params['id'];

    }


    ngOnInit() {
        this.sectionService.getSections()
            .subscribe((data: Response) => {
                 this.sections = data.json();        
            }, err => {
                console.error("Error occurred while saving setting", err);
            }, () => {
                this.groupService.getGroups(this.sections[0].Id).subscribe((data: Response) => {
                    this.groups = data.json();
                })
            });

    }

}

export class Group {
    isSelectionComponentOpened: boolean;
    isItemEditComponentOpened: boolean;
    Id: string;
    Title: string;
    SectionId: string;
    Items: Array<string>
}

export class Section {
    Id: string;
    Title: string;

}




@Injectable()
export class SectionService {


    constructor(private http: Http) { }
    // Переделать на Observable
    getSections() {
        return this.http.get('Section/Get');
    }
}
```

I can't figure out the cause of this problem.
Please advise.

Comment: It's angular 2, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

use `let _self = this;` in `ngOnInit`

such as

```
@Component({
    template: require('./content.component.html'),
    styles: [require('./content.component.css')],

})
export class ContentComponent {
    id: string;
    sections: Array<Section>;
    groups: Array<Group>
    selectedSectionTitle: "";
    constructor(private router: Router, private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute, private sectionService: SectionService, private groupService: GroupService) {
        this.router.events.subscribe(path => {
            this.id = activateRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
        });
        this.id = activateRoute.snapshot.params['id'];

    }


    ngOnInit() {
        let _self = this;
        this.sectionService.getSections()
            .subscribe((data: Response) => {
                 _self.sections = data.json();        
            }, err => {
                console.error("Error occurred while saving setting", err);
            }, () => {
                this.groupService.getGroups(_self.sections[0].Id).subscribe((data: Response) => {
                    _self.groups = data.json();
                })
            });

    }

}

export class Group {
    isSelectionComponentOpened: boolean;
    isItemEditComponentOpened: boolean;
    Id: string;
    Title: string;
    SectionId: string;
    Items: Array<string>
}

export class Section {
    Id: string;
    Title: string;

}




@Injectable()
export class SectionService {


    constructor(private http: Http) { }
    // Переделать на Observable
    getSections() {
        return this.http.get('Section/Get');
    }
}
```

add `providers: [SectionService, GroupService]` in module.ts which will avoid making instances of service

Comment: it will hold your value of `this` in variable `_self` which will help to not being out of scope

Comment: OP is already using the fat arrow syntax. Problem is not with the scope, it's about the async operation

Comment: also add `providers: [SectionService, GroupService]` in module.ts only which will avoid making instances of service

Comment: I've done some checking.
This didn't quite help.
sections[0].id is now nan.
It seems to be the async operation.

Any advice please?

Comment: is `sections[0].Id` a Number or use `+` before it to convert to number as `+sections[0].Id`

Comment: This was of no help.
The value of self.sections is undefined.

Comment: plz try `ngOnInit() {
        let _self = this;
        this.sectionService.getSections()
            .subscribe((data: Response) => {
                _self.sections = data.json(); 
    this.groupService.getGroups(_self.sections[0].Id).subscribe((data: Response) => {
     _self.groups = data.json();
    });
            }, err => {
                console.error("Error occurred while saving setting", err);
            });

    }`

Comment: I have tried this approach previously on my own.
This was of no help.
Console logging the value has also shown an undefined value.
Howeever, debugging in chrome gave the right value..

what could this be?

Answer (score 0):

This was the oddest thing I have encountered.
But changing the section Id property to lowercase helped...

I do not have an explanation for this fix.